# Troubleshooting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: python, discord.py

At the moment this snippet is from a command that logically works, except for sending the embed to the respective channel.

```
@bot.command(name="share")
@commands.dm_only()
async def on_message(ctx):
#other logic that I used such as a cooldown and so on
#function primarily takes a user's DM and shares to a channel inside a server
.....

if message.guild is None and not message.author.bot:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        t = now.strftime('%A %Y/%m/%d  %I:%M %p')
        print("A User Has Shared A Link. \nUserID: {}\nTime is: {}".format(
            message.author.id, t))
        print(message.content + "\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n")
        
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Shared Message: ",
                              description=message.content, color=(0x92f852))
        embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        embed.set_footer(text="Stay Frostyyy",icon_url="") #redacted image url
        channel = bot.get_channel(863712965525766144)
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

All the logic prior to the chanel=bot.get_channel line works just the few lines after is causing the issue. The issue I am running into is the channel.send(embed=embed) line because of an error:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'`
Would appreciate any help!

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get%20channel#discord.Client.get_channel your bot is unable to find the channel

Comment: Consider editing your title to something the specifically indicates the problem you are trying to solve.  "Have an issue" doesn't help people find your question.

Comment: @RyanSchaefer now that you mention that, I went and double checked the bot has the ability to read and write to the specified channel, along with the bot permissions for the server. No dice.
I don't think it has to do with intents either

Comment: It doesn't have to do with intents, since `get_channel` only requires `Intents.guilds`, which is enabled by default. Can you try to fetch through the API call? Do `await bot.fetch_channel(ID)`.

Comment: I'm confused by how your code is working. The first part shows decorators that are for commands, but you named the coro 'on_message' and then you keep using logic that would point that you're on a message handler, not in a command, like `process_commands`. I bet there's something in that logic that prevents the guild from actually being on your bot's cache. Why don't you try `ctx.bot` instead of `bot`? They should be the same but try it out. If not, then yeah, your bot has no access to that channel